# Validation: clean() and clean_<fieldname> not working as expected

Tags: django

I have to validate a field if it's unique. I am not using unique=True in models. I am using clean() and clean_() in forms but are raising different errors.

**forms.py**
Case 1: clean()

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Package Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    def clean(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if Package.objects.filter(name=name):
            raise ValidationError(_("Package with this package name already exist."))
        return name
```

case 2: clean_name()

```
name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Package Name', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
        if Package.objects.filter(name=name):
            raise ValidationError(_("Package with this package name already exist."))
        return name
```

**views.py**

```
def create_package(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePackageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            package = Package()
            package.name = form.clean()



            if request.POST.get('subscription', False):

                package.subscription = True
                package.billing = request.POST['billing']
                package.billing_after = str(request.POST['billing_days']) +' '+ request.POST['billing_unit']
            else:
                package.subscription = False

            package.save()

            return redirect('packages')



    else:
        form = CreatePackageForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, 'fitness/create_package.html', context)
```

**in html template:**

```
<p style="color:red;">{{ form.non_field_errors.as_text }}</p>
```

**Problem:**
 in case 1, validation is correct if I send duplicate name but if name is unique, this gives this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

In case 2:
 if name is valid, then everything ok. data is saving normally but if it's duplicate data, it's not showing error message. But validation is working as it's not submitting the form.

Comment: The `package.name = form.clean_name() or package.name = form.clean()` statement does not seem to make much sense?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not set the model field to `unique=True`? This might be a lot easier than trying to implement this yourself, and furthermore the database can protect the data integrity as well.

Comment: Please show the whole view. As Willem says, that line doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I have edited views.py. And I not am using unique=True because I want to show error on page, and also I have to use validations on different forms where validation is only way. (although I have used unique=True for safty)

Comment: But the updated view doesn't show that code at all. And why are you ignoring the form and going back to get the data straight from request.POST?

Comment: it's package.name = form.clean()

Comment: But this is basically nonsense, I'm afraid. Please show the rest of the code of your form.